# Using JavaScript to change width of div

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use JavaScript to change the width of a div, but something's wrong with one part of my code. I think it's this part:

```
document.getElementById("div").style["width"] = width+"px";
```

I'm not sure what's wrong with it, so if you know, please let me know. Thanks.

```
<script>

function adapt (percentage) {

var width = percentage/100;
var width = window.innerWidth*width;

document.getElementById("div").style["width"] = width+"px";

}

adapt(80);

</script>
```

```
<style>

div {
border: 1px solid black;
}

</style>

<div id = 'div'> </div>
```

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/ozajqucz/

Comment: it's working perfectly

Comment: Is your Javascript in the `head` section of the page?

Comment: Can you show us a fiddle? Where is your JavaScript located?

Comment: @Purag No. It's not in the head.

Comment: Okay, is it anywhere in the code *before* the `div` itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your Javascript appears before the element in the code. Browsers process HTML documents top-down, so your Javascript gets executed before there's even an element to act upon.

You can either put the function call inside a `window.onload` wrapper, or put the `<script>` tag after the `div`. Usually, it is placed at the end of the `<body>` tag since all elements will have been processed by the browser at that point.